# dynamic google form inside flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, google-forms

can I redirect the user to a google form, that has values from database?

let's say I'm presenting hours from 1-5
and I want each user to has his own hour.

so, if user x submit hour 1
then I'll prevent user y from choosing the same value he will be able to choose from 2-5 only